# Is there any modification of Escape sequence (\r ,\f,\b)property in java new version

Tags: java

I don't know the exact use of \f - form feed escape sequence,so I searched some examples from that i come to know that it has been used for page break(Insert a form feed in the text at this point).
So when I run the the following program,I got some different result for /f,/b and /r is there any reason?
Share your opinion on this,Point out if I done anything wrong.
java version "1.8.0_181"

```
      System.out.println("Backspace      : " + "ABCDE\bFGHIJ");
      System.out.println("Formfeed       : " + "ABCDE\fFGHIJ");
      System.out.println("Backslash      : " + "ABCDE\\FGHIJ");
      System.out.println("Carriage Return: " + "ABCDE\rFGHIJ");

 OUTPUT
    Backspace      : ABCDEFGHIJ
    Formfeed       : ABCDEFGHIJ
    Backslash      : ABCDE\FGHIJ
    Carriage Return: ABCDE
    FGHIJ
```

Comment: When you say you got "some different result[s]", what were they different from?

Comment: I expect this output:`Backspace      : ABCDFGHIJ
Formfeed       : ABCDE
                      FGHIJ
Backslash      : ABCDE\FGHIJ
FGHIJage Return: ABCDE`

Comment: And those different results were obtained...how? Same code running under a different (presumably older) version of Java?

Comment: I don't know, may be it works for older version.That's why I asked.

Comment: So you've _actually seen_ the expected output produced in the past (which is why you're expecting it)?

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes

Answer (score 1):

Well obviously *something* has changed between the time you saw your expected results and today when you are getting your unexpected results.   But I doubt it has anything to do with the escapes themselves as, from a backward-compatibility point of view, they must continue to represent the same characters in every new version of Java.

So, any differences you're seeing are due to how the characters are handled once they've be sent out to `System.out`.  It *could* be something to do with the particular version of Java, either in the JDK libraries or in the JVM.   But it could equally well be something entirely outside of Java.  For instance, a DOS-emulation box on Windows might display these characters differently than an output window in an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse. There might even be a difference between the DOS boxes on different versions of Windows, or the output windows on different versions of the same IDE.

The only way to know for sure is to run your program under different Java versions in controlled conditions where **everything** else besides the Java version  remains identical. However, there's no guarantee it's even possible to achieve those test conditions.  So if I were you I'd just accept that there's no guarantee about how these characters will be displayed and not let it bother you any further.

If you're curious about Form Feed `'\f'` specifically, it's historical purpose was, as you may have surmised, to cause an output device, usually a printer, to advance to the top of a new page. For for software-emulated display pseudo-devices like DOS-boxes and IDE output windows that don't have a well-defined concept of what a "page" is, advancing to a new page is basically meaningless.  So what should happen when you send a formfeed to one of these displays?  Clear the window?  Jump down ten lines (or five or twenty)? Display a little one-character-wide "FF" graphic? Display a blank space? Ignore it and display nothing at all?  Who knows? It all depends on what the programmers of DOS-boxes and IDE output windows and other such software-emulated display pseudo-devices decided they ought to do.